# How do I save a model instead of a checkpoint?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was following this tutorial, but when I wanted to convert the .h5 file into .pb I found out that I can't use checkpoints.

https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/skin-cancer-detection-using-tensorflow-in-python

Please explain this to me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use model.save() to save the model in .pb format. For more information read [Tensorflow SavedModel format](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#savedmodel_format).

```
import tensorflow as tf
#Load .h5 saved model
pre_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("final_model.h5")
#Converts .pb format
pre_model.save("saved_model/my_model")
```